# Schedule a message in Rabbitmq

Tags: docker, go, rabbitmq

I'm trying to follow the official tutorial, but also adding the possibility to delay/schedule a message in RabbitMQ. I've my setup running in docker with `rabbitmq:3-management-alpine` and I've been trying to set the `x-delay` header, but messages still get sent instantly.

**send.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    amqp "github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    body := "Hello World!"
    err = ch.PublishWithContext(ctx,
        "",     // exchange
        q.Name, // routing key
        false,  // mandatory
        false,  // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            Headers: map[string]interface{}{
                "x-delay": 5000,
            },
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        []byte(body),
        })
    failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")
    log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s\n", body)
}
```

**receive.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    amqp "github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    var forever chan struct{}

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to schedule a message you need to publish a message to the exchange with specific properties defined, which you don't do in the code you have provided.
Here is an example of how to declare the exchange which supports scheduling(taken from [official](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2015/04/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq) documentation):

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
channel.exchangeDeclare("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
```

Then this is the way you publish(again taken from official documentation):

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = "delayed payload".getBytes();
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder();
headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("x-delay", 5000);
props.headers(headers);
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "", props.build(), messageBodyBytes);
```

PS: sorry for not providing examples in Go, I'm sure you can figure out how set things up using Go library